# LWJGL - Application Crash

Tags: java, lwjgl

I learned the basics of Java and I want to use LWJGL. I found tutorials [here](https://github.com/SilverTiger/lwjgl3-tutorial/blob/master/src/silvertiger/tutorial/lwjgl/Introduction.java). I copy this code:

```
package simple;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import org.lwjgl.system.Configuration;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

public class Introduction {
    /**
     * This error callback will simply print the error to
     * <code>System.err</code>.
     */
    private static GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback
            = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err);


    /**
     * The main function will create a 640x480 window and renders a rotating
     * triangle until the window gets closed.
     *
     */
    public void run() {
        long window;

        /* Set the error callback */
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);

        /* Initialize GLFW */
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }

        /* Create window */
        window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            glfwTerminate();
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
        }

        /* Center the window on screen */
        GLFWVidMode vidMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window,
                (vidMode.width() - 640) / 2,
                (vidMode.height() - 480) / 2
        );

        /* Create OpenGL context */
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        GL.createCapabilities();

        /* Enable vertical synchronization */
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        /* Declare buffers for using inside the loop */
        IntBuffer width = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        IntBuffer height = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

        /* Loop until window gets closed */
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            float ratio;

            /* Get width and height to calcualte the ratio */
            glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, width, height);
            ratio = width.get() / (float) height.get();

            /* Rewind buffers for next get */
            width.rewind();
            height.rewind();

            /* Set viewport and clear screen */
            glViewport(0, 0, width.get(), height.get());
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            /* Set ortographic projection */
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1f, 1f, 1f, -1f);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

            /* Rotate matrix */
            glLoadIdentity();
            glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50f, 0f, 0f, 1f);

            /* Render triangle */
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0f);
            glColor3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0f);
            glColor3f(0f, 0f, 1f);
            glVertex3f(0f, 0.6f, 0f);
            glEnd();

            /* Swap buffers and poll Events */
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();

            /* Flip buffers for next loop */
            width.flip();
            height.flip();
        }

        /* Release window and its callbacks */
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        /* Terminate GLFW and release the error callback */
        glfwTerminate();
        errorCallback.free();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            unpackNatives();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize LWJGL", ex);
        }
        new Introduction().run();
    }

    /**
     * This method loads the natives libraries required by LWJGL. The specified
     * libraries will get extracted into the folder native.
     *
     * @throw IOException if an error occurs during extracting the libraries
     */
    private static void unpackNatives() throws IOException {
        Path libraryPath = Paths.get("native");

        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

        /* Mac OS X needs headless mode for AWT */
        if (os.contains("mac")) {
            System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
        }

        /* Only unpack if native folder doesn't exist */
        if (!Files.exists(libraryPath)) {
            /* Get architecture */
            String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase();

            /* Check if JVM is 64 bit */
            boolean is64bit = arch.equals("amd64") || arch.equals("x86_64");

            /* Extract libraries */
            if (!Files.isDirectory(libraryPath)) {
                Files.createDirectory(libraryPath);
            } else if (Files.exists(libraryPath)) {
                return;
            }
            String[] libraries;
            if (os.contains("win")) {
                /* Windows */
                if (is64bit) {
                    libraries = new String[]{
                            "lwjgl.dll",
                            "glfw.dll",
                            "OpenAL.dll",
                            "jemalloc.dll"
                    };
                } else {
                    libraries = new String[]{
                            "lwjgl32.dll",
                            "glfw32.dll",
                            "OpenAL32.dll",
                            "jemalloc32.dll"
                    };
                }
            } else if (os.contains("mac")) {
                /* Mac OS X */
                libraries = new String[]{
                        "liblwjgl.dylib",
                        "libglfw.dylib",
                        "libopenal.dylib",
                        "libjemalloc.dylib"
                };

            } else if (os.contains("nix") || os.contains("nux") || os.indexOf("aix") > 0) {
                /* Linux */
                if (is64bit) {
                    libraries = new String[]{
                            "liblwjgl.so",
                            "libglfw.so",
                            "libopenal.so",
                            "libjemalloc.so"
                    };
                } else {
                    libraries = new String[]{
                            "liblwjgl32.so",
                            "libglfw32.so",
                            "libopenal32.so",
                            "libjemalloc32.so"
                    };
                }
            } else {
                /* Not supported */
                throw new RuntimeException("Operating System "
                        + System.getProperty("os.name") + " is not supported");
            }
            for (String library : libraries) {
                Files.copy(Introduction.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + library), libraryPath.resolve(library),
                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
        }

        /* Set LWJGL library path */
        Configuration.LIBRARY_PATH.set(libraryPath.toString());
    }

}
```

But, when i run my application (with `gradlew run`)

```
Execution protection violation
                               #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000, pid=10676, tid=4436
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Yoann\IdeaProjects\simple.project\hs_err_pid10676.log
                                                                                                                       #
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Please provide the hs_err_pid10676.log file so the issue can be recognized.

Comment: From the above I assume you either haven't included the necessary libraries. Or you are missing a library.